# Create Vector Sequence Based off of Initial Variables and Function

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I need help creating a vector sequence in R using an initial starting element, and calculating the next next element in the vector sequence based off of the previous vector element.

Here is what I want to do. The first element (z) of the vector is going to be defined as:

z = (X * Y) + X

So if X = 100, Y = 0.14, then Z = 114.

I then want to take that new z and call it x for the time we calculate. So then the cycles repeats, with y staying constant, and 114 become the new x value.

So Z =(114, 129.96, 148.15, ...) and so on.

I had thought some combination of `seq()` and `rollapply()` would work, but I'm yet to figure it out. I'm working with data frames, and this is small part of more complex calculation I'm trying to perform.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be cool, nonloopy, and more generalizable:

```
value = 114
nout <- 10
y <- .14
v <- Reduce(function(v, x) y*v +v, x=numeric(nout),  init=value, accumulate=TRUE)
[1] 114.0000 129.9600 148.1544 168.8960 192.5415 
[6] 219.4973 250.2269 285.2586 325.1949 370.7221
```

But given your use case, a `for` loop would also work fine, and is **more** readable:

```
X <- 100
Y <- .14
z <- rep(NA, 10)
z[1] <- (X * Y) + X
for(i in 2:length(z)){
  z[i] <- (z[i-1] * y) + z[i-1]
}

z
[1] 114.0000 129.9600 148.1544 168.8960 192.5415 
[6] 219.4973 250.2269 285.2586 325.1949 370.7221
```

Comment: perfect, this more generalized solution is going to help a lot with some other stuff I'm working on

Comment: @SerbanTanasa I'll start stockpiling an assortment of candy for future use

Answer (score 2):

Let's do a little math:

```
z = x * y + x 
  = x * (y + 1)
```

So your sequence is

```
x,
x * (y + 1), 
x * (y + 1) * (y + 1), ...
```

Which is to say

```
z_i = x * (y + 1) ^ (i - 1)
```

Since all the arithmetic operations in R are vectorized, including `^`, this is simple to code:

```
x = 100
y = 0.14
x * (y + 1) ^ (0:10)
# [1] 100.0000 114.0000 129.9600 148.1544 168.8960 192.5415 219.4973 250.2269 285.2586
# [10] 325.1949 370.7221
```

No loops or fancy functions needed. You can replace `10` in my code by however many iterations you'd like.

Comment: I'll give you the parsimonious, but mine's more generalizable.

Comment: thanks, I should have broken it down like you did. I have the bad habit of trying to find the "perfect" function for each scenario

Answer (score 1):

You could write a for loop:

```
# Starting values
x <- 100 + 14
y <- .14
z <- 114


# For loop with 100 iterations:
for(i in 2:100) {
  z[i] <- (x * y) + x
  x <- z[i]
}
```

All calculated values will be stored in z.

Comment: Thx for the advice, fixed it